# iterate a dataframe list to find difference between the value in the list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing a column named Price:

```
 Day Price
 Mon  20
 Tue  42
 Wed  89
 Thu  65
 Fri  78
 Sat  67
```

I need to find the change in the price:

```
Change in price = (present day price - previous day price)/ previous day price
```

I know we can find the change in price by "diff" but i am unable to iterate the list according to the above formula.
How can i do this using pandas?

Comment: [`Series.pct_change`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.pct_change.html) -> `df['Price'].pct_change()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd


days = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat']
prices = [20, 42, 89, 65, 78, 67]

val_dict = {'Day': days, 'Price': prices}


df = pd.DataFrame(val_dict)

df['ChangeInPrice'] = (df.Price - df.Price.shift(1)) / df.Price.shift(1)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   Day  Price  ChangeInPrice
0  Mon     20            NaN
1  Tue     42       1.100000
2  Wed     89       1.119048
3  Thu     65      -0.269663
4  Fri     78       0.200000
5  Sat     67      -0.141026
```

Answer (score -2):

The easy way to do it is assigning a new column with the result

```
df['change_pct'] = df['price'].pct_change()
```

Pandas has some great functions to deal with this operation as mentioned in the comments.

I would like to say that you can also use [Apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and define your own function to do any kind of calculation row-by-row

Comment: [`Shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) would be a better doc to reference than `apply` in this case since apply wouldn't be able to access previous rows information. `(df['Price'] - df['Price'].shift()) / df['Price'].shift()`

Comment: Yes I agree that apply wouldn't be able to access the previous row without shift(). In that context, apply is a bit redundant but obviously useful in other cases.